# How can I use SafeViewFlipper?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to use SafeViewFlipper (http://pastie.org/1086467) [Crash when rotating Activity using ViewFlipper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674796/crash-when-rotating-activity-using-viewflipper)

but I don't know how to do it..

When I try this the application crashes (ClassCastException)

```
SafeViewFlipper controlsFlipper;
controlsFlipper = (SafeViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.controlsFlipper);
```

in the layout.xml..

```
<ViewFlipper android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/controlsFlipper">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference the SafeViewFlipper in xml with the full package name. E.g.

`<com.example.view.SafeViewFlipper android:layout_width="fill_parent" ..... />`